# Python numpy (einsum) optimization: 1D to ND outer dot products

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, dot-product

How can I most efficiently compute the dot products of 2 ND outer products from 1D arrays?

"i,j,k,l->ij,kl->" would be a nice einsum alternative but that fails.

```
invalid subscript ',' in einstein sum subscripts string, subscripts must be letters
```

Below are the naive implementations I'm trying to speed up (A and B will be other things).  The ideal would be a fast version with the following API which would have the same result as the following examples: nd_outer_from1D(2, A, B), nd_outer_from1D(3, A, B).  As you'll see, as |A|, |B|, and N increase storing the result and reinserting back into einsum as arguments quickly becomes infeasible.

```
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(50); B=np.arange(50); sum(sum(np.outer(A,A) * np.outer(B,B)))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.1 usec per loop
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(50); B=np.arange(50); sum(sum(np.einsum("i,j->ij",A,A) * np.einsum("i,j->ij",B,B)  ))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.4 usec per loop
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(50); B=np.arange(50); sum(sum(sum(np.einsum("i,j,k->ijk",A,A,A) * np.einsum("i,j,k->ijk",B,B,B)  )))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 msec per loop
```

Edit (example):

```
>>> A
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> B
array([0.58394169, 0.22495002, 0.08322459, 0.05406281])
>>> sum(sum(np.einsum('i,j->ij',A,A) * np.einsum('i,j->ij', B, B)))
0.3064592592321492
```

Apparently sum(sum( and the leading einsum did not work as I expected.

Piece of cake for the gurus below, comparing times:

```
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(50); B=np.arange(50); np.einsum("i,i->",A,B)**3'
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.77 usec per loop
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(50); B=np.arange(50); np.einsum("i,i->",A,B)**2'
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.63 usec per loop
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(50); B=np.arange(50); A.dot(B)**3'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.75 usec per loop
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(50); B=np.arange(50); A.dot(B)**2'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.68 usec per loop
```

Wow, this is faster than I expected:

```
$  python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; A=np.arange(5000); B=np.arange(5000); A.dot(B)**10'
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 usec per loop
```

Comment: Now, the edits having me confused. What if the lengths of arrays are not the same as with the timing codes?

Comment: The lengths should be the same, I made a typo, sorry about the confusion.  The idea is that I build an ND cube out of A and a similarly sized ND cube from B then dot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be optimized with `einsum` -

```
np.einsum("i,i->",A,B)**2
```

With `matrix-multiplication` -

```
A.dot(B)**2
```

Answer (score 1):

Can still just be done with `einsum`:

```
np.einsum('i, j, j, i', A, A, B, B)
Out: 0.30645926408901691
```

Comment: Amazing, I had tried something so close: np.einsum('i, j, k, l', A, A, B, B)... Do you know of a way to do an ND version of that?